# No response from node js (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I send `request` from React with:

```
export const loadItems = () => async dispatch => {
  await axios
    .get("http://localhost:8000/api/users")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.users);
      dispatch(dataLoaded(response.users));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(dataLoadFailed(err));
    });
};
```

But there is no `response`, and the server does not take `request`, here is my server app code:

server.js

```
// a lot of requires
const todoRoutes = require("./routes/serverRoute");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/taskManager";
const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
  url,
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else console.log("Database connected");
  }
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/index.html"));
});

// cors allow
app.use("/api", todoRoutes);

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("API started");
});
```

And this is a controller I use, it's all good with `Schema` and DB, I checked with output to console from the node, `users` is defined and contains data

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/UserModel");

module.exports = {
  getUsers(req, res) {
    User.find().exec((err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.send({ err });
      } else {
        console.log(users);
        return res.send({ users });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

And this is my router:

```
module.exports = router => {
  router.get('/users', userController.getUsers);
}
```

Comment: Should be `return await` In you first snippet.

Comment: @Strelok it was good when I used `app.get` in `server.js`, but now I tried to make it work with `mongoose`, and it's corrupted

Comment: btw it's `arrow` func, it's return `axios` promise result in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it on my own. Problem was here:

`router.get('/users', userController.getUsers);`

It supposed to be like this:

`router.get('/users', userController.getUsers());`